# How do I sample a variable from the same path at two different time points and do this 1000 times, to compute covariance?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to show the covariance of an ARIMA process. My previous attempt was to use R's replicate function, however that resulted in the wrong covariance value being computed.

Please see my feedback from my Professor:

I'm trying to show the covariance of an ARIMA process. Acc
To compute the sample covariance between `X_3 and X_7`, you have to sample `t = 3 and t = 7` from the same path, and do this 1000 times. Your code right now draws them separately---using replicate() in line 100.

Comment: Could you please show us the code that he was commenting on?

Comment: Yes no problem @G5W , I apologise if the syntax is not correct:                                                                             
                                                                                                              `samplepath2<-replicate(1000,arima.sim(n=100, model = AR.sm))
expectedvalue.1<-mean(samplepath2[3,])
variance.1<-var(samplepath2[3,])
covariance.1<-cov(samplepath2[3,],samplepath2[7,])`